# Converting JSON date value into format "Day, Month"

Tags: java, android, json, date, datetime

I have an SQL database linked to a web service. The web service will send JSON data to my android application using JAVA.

The date was stored as DATETIME in SQL, and displayed as "11/14/2017 12:00:00 AM" in web service. The JSON data received for date on the android application are "2017-11-14T00:00:00".

How can i format it to show "14 November" using Java?

Following codes shows how i retrieved the json data:

```
    JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            for (int j = 0; j < response.length(); j++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject temp=response.getJSONObject(j);
                    String date = temp.getString("Date")
                    Log.v("Date", date);

                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
```

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what you have tried so far ? for parsing date time string

Comment: @LakshayJuneja edited with codes that shows how i retrieved the json data

Comment: @KimSuYu i am asking about your date time parsing not about how you are getting response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
// format date
String dt = "2017-11-14T00:00:00";
// old SimpleDateFormat 
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
// new SimpleDateFormat 
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = null;
    try {
    date = sdf1.parse(dt);
    String newDate = sdf2.format(date);
    System.out.println(newDate);
    Log.e("Date", newDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class, at least not as the first option and without reservation. Today we have so much better in [JSR-310, the modern Java date and time API also known as `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Thank you for your comment .I got it .

Answer (score 0):

Use  **java.text.SimpleDateFormat** as [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-simpledateformat) tutorial.

```
public static String convertDate(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat fromFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date dt = fromFormat.parse(date);
        return new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM").format(dt);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar`  instance return day, month and year, below code will return month and date

```
 JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int j = 0; j < response.length(); j++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject temp=response.getJSONObject(j);
                        String date = temp.getString("Date")
                        Log.v("Date", date);
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                        Date parse = sdf.parse(date);//date variable your json value
                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        c.setTime(parse);
                        System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + c.get(Calendar.DATE));

                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
```

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` for convert in desired format like :

```
SimpleDateFormat Dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.US);
Date date =   Dateformat.parse(YourDateString);
String StringDate = Dateformat .format(date);
String MyNewDate= StringDate.split(" ")[0]+ StringDate.split(" ")[1];
```